# Pushforward of smooth section is smooth?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields, noncommutative-geometry

---

This is the **main** question:

> if $p:A \rightarrow B$ is a smooth vector bundle homomoprhism over base space $M$, then $pX$ is a smooth section of $B$, where $X \in \Gamma(A)$ is a smooth section of $A$.

---

I think the claim is simply true in local coordinates, being composition of smooth maps.

---

If the above claim is not true. Here is more context. I am reading [page 10, Definition 1.5](http://math.univ-bpclermont.fr/~debord/coursColombie.pdf) of the notes which defines a **Lie algebroid**.

---

> let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and let $p:A \rightarrow TM$ be a bundle homomorphism. Then we require it to satisfy, 
>   $$ [pX,pY]_{TM}= p[X,Y]_A$$
>   $X,Y \in \Gamma(A)$, the space of smooth sections. The Lie brackets are with respect to the spaces $\Gamma(TM)$ and $\Gamma(A)$.

My question is, how are the terms well defined - is it guaranteed that $pX$ is still a smooth vector field over $M$?